# Проблема с конструктором

Tags: c++

проблема в работе конструктора с параметрами и оператора `<<`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Distance
{
    int feet;
    int inches;
    Distance():feet(0),inches(0.0)
    {}
    Distance(int ft,float in):feet(ft),inches(in)
    {}
    void getlist()
    {
        cout<<"vvedi fut:";cin>>feet;
        cout<<"vvedi duim:";cin>>inches;
    }
    void showlist()
    {
        cout<<feet<<"\-"<<inches<<endl;
    }

};
void main()
{
    Distance dist1(12,9.5);//ошибка подчеркивает 12
    Distance dist2(dist1);
    Distance dist3 = dist1;
    cout<<"d1="<<dist1.showlist();//ошибка отсутствует оператор соот. этим операндам 
    cout<<"d2="<<dist2.showlist();
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Обратите внимание, что inches. у вас int, а вы туда пихаете число с плавающей точкой двойной точности (0.0)

Answer (score 3):

Вы, похоже, пользуетесь компилятором от Майкрософта. А он ужасен. Так как gcc или clang сразу бы подсказали, где ошибки.

1. `Distance dist1(12,9.5);` - ошибка в другом месте. Конструктор-то у Вас приватный! Поэтому его нужно поместить в секцию `public`.
2. `cout<<"d1="<<dist1.showlist();` `showlist` имеет тип void, то есть ничего не возвращает. А ничего сложно вывести на консоль. Я переписал вывод, хотя можно было бы переписать функцию showlist.
3. `void main()` - по стандарту так писать нельзя. Нужно как минимум писать `int main()`. И не забыть `return 0;` в конец.

Исправленный код (он компилируется, но не факт, что именно это Вы хотели):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Distance
{
private:
    int feet;
    int inches;
public:
    Distance():feet(0),inches(0.0)
    {}
    Distance(int ft,float in):feet(ft),inches(in)
    {}
    void getlist()
    {
        cout<<"vvedi fut:";cin>>feet;
        cout<<"vvedi duim:";cin>>inches;
    }
    void showlist(string p)
    {
        cout << p <<feet<<"-"<<inches<<endl;
    }

};
int main()
{
    Distance dist1(12,9.5);//ошибка подчеркивает 12
    Distance dist2(dist1);
    Distance dist3 = dist1;
    dist1.showlist("d1=");//ошибка отсутствует оператор соот. этим операндам 
    dist2.showlist("d2=");
    return 0;
}
```